# Postgres large numeric value operations

Tags: postgresql, numeric

I am trying some operations on large numeric field such as 2^89.

Postgres numeric data type can store 131072 on left of decimal and 16383 digits on right of decimal.

I tried some thing like this and it worked:

```
select 0.037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037037::numeric;
```

But when I put some operator, it rounds off values after 14 digits.

```
select (2^89)::numeric(40,0);

           numeric              
-----------------------------   
 618970019642690000000000000    
(1 row)
```

I know the value from elsewhere is:

```
>>> 2**89
618970019642690137449562112
```

Why is this strange behavior. It is not letting me enter values beyond 14 digits numeric to database.

```
insert into x select (2^89-1)::numeric;

 select * from x;        
              x                 
-----------------------------   
 618970019642690000000000000    
(1 row)
```

Is there any way to circumvent this.

Thanks in advance.

bb23850

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not cast the result but one part of the operation to make clear that this is a `numeric` operation, not an `integer` operation:

```
select (2^89::numeric)
```

Otherwise PostgreSQL takes the `2` and the `89` as type `integer`. In that case the result is type `integer`, too, which is not an exact value at that size. Your cast is a cast of that inaccurate result, so it cannot work.

Comment: Perfect. Solves my problem. Thanks a lot.